# A logo and responsive navigation within the same line using bootstrap

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, navbar, fluid

I am trying to use bootstrap to make a responsive navigation bar.

> What I want is I have a logo on the left side and the navigation right beside the logo.
>
> I want EACH navigation (Home, About Us, Our Services, Contact  Us) have the same width and fluid, so if I adjust the screen size, the
> navigation bar will resize and the logo stay the same.

But whenever I tried to resize the screen into smaller size, the navigation bar is not in the same line anymore.

**normal screen size:** https://www.dropbox.com/s/bl9s3m6ph79vrq0/1.PNG?dl=0

**smaller screen size** (navigation is not on the same line as logo): https://www.dropbox.com/s/55cu1xyfi37rrp2/2.PNG?dl=0

**css**

```
.navbar-brand{
padding-top: 0;
padding-left: 0px;
padding-right: 15px;
width: 18%;
}

.navbar-header{
display: block;}

ul{
padding-top: 60px;
}

.navbar-nav{
width: 80%;
}


.nav li{
display: block;
width: 25%;
text-align: center;
}

#logo_img{
width: 220px;
}
```

**html**

```
<nav class="navbar navbar-default">
    <div class="container-fluid">
    
        <div class="navbar-header">
            <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle collapsed" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#bs-example-navbar-collapse-1" aria-expanded="false">
                <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
                <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                <span class="icon-bar"></span>
            </button>
            <a class="navbar-brand" href="#"><img id="logo_img" width="220" src="Assets/logo.png"></a>
        </div>

        <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="bs-example-navbar-collapse-1">
            <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
                <li><a href="#">Home</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">About Us</a></li>
                <li class="dropdown">
                    <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" role="button" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">Our Services <span class="caret"></span></a>
                    <ul class="dropdown-menu">
                        <li><a href="#">Videography</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">Design</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">Training</a></li>
                    </ul>
                </li>
                <li><a href="#">Contact Us</a></li>
            </ul>
        </div><!--end of collapse-->

    </div><!--end of container fluid-->
</nav>
```

I already found the same condition with me here [Bootstrap logo on same line as navbar items](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29775623/bootstrap-logo-on-same-line-as-navbar-items)
but I still can't figure out what is wrong. Thanks before!

Comment: How large is the logo you are using, 220px wide + ??? height? Some screenshots of the problem, and of what you want, would also help. The text description isn't quite clear on that.

Comment: I already add the image. the logo are 220px * 85px

Answer (score 1):

This is the CSS you can use to place your image **(remove your img link from navbar-brand and replace it inside the CSS)**.

```
.navbar-brand {
width: 220px;
height: 50px;
background: url('http://placehold.it/220x85') no-repeat center center;
background-size: 150px;
}
```

Evenly spacing your navbar links can be done will CSS and the use of media queries but be aware that if you need to add links it can get ugly and complicated.

See Snippet.

```css
.navbar {
  border-radius: 0px;
  border: transparent;
}
.nav li {
  width: 150px;
  text-align: center;
}
.dropdown-menu li {
  text-align: left;
}
.navbar-brand {
  width: 220px;
  height: 50px;
  background: url('http://placehold.it/220x85') no-repeat center center;
  background-size: 150px;
}
.dropdown-submenu {
  position: relative;
}
.dropdown-submenu > .dropdown-menu {
  top: 0;
  left: 100%;
  margin-top: -6px;
  margin-left: -1px;
  -webkit-border-radius: 0px;
  -moz-border-radius: 0px 6px 6px 6px;
  border-radius: 0px;
}
.dropdown-submenu:hover > .dropdown-menu {
  display: block;
}
.dropdown-submenu > a:after {
  display: block;
  content: " ";
  float: right;
  width: 0px;
  height: 0px;
  border-color: transparent;
  border-style: solid;
  border-width: 5px 0px 5px 5px;
  border-left-color: #cccccc;
  margin-top: 5px;
  margin-right: -10px;
}
.dropdown-submenu:hover > a:after {
  border-left-color: #ffffff;
}
.dropdown-submenu.pull-left {
  float: none;
}
.dropdown-submenu.pull-left > .dropdown-menu {
  left: -100%;
  margin-left: 10px;
  -webkit-border-radius: 6px 0px 6px 6px;
  -moz-border-radius: 6px 0px 6px 6px;
  border-radius: 6px 0px 6px 6px;
}
@media only screen and (max-width: 992px) {
  .nav li {
    width: auto;
  }
}
@media only screen and (max-width: 768px) {
  .nav li {
    width: auto;
    text-align: left;
  }
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.5.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<nav role="navigation" class="navbar navbar-default">
  <!-- Brand and toggle get grouped for better mobile display -->
  <div class="navbar-header">
    <button type="button" data-target="#navbarCollapse" data-toggle="collapse" class="navbar-toggle"> <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
      <span class="icon-bar"></span>
      <span class="icon-bar"></span>
      <span class="icon-bar"></span>

    </button>
    <a href="#" class="navbar-brand"></a>

  </div>
  <!-- Collection of nav links, forms, and other content for toggling -->
  <div id="navbarCollapse" class="collapse navbar-collapse">
    <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
      <li class="active"><a href="#">Home</a>

      </li>
      <li><a href="#">Profile</a>

      </li>
      <li class="dropdown"> <a data-toggle="dropdown" class="dropdown-toggle" href="#">Messages <b class="caret"></b></a>

        <ul role="menu" class="dropdown-menu">
          <li><a href="#"><i class="fa fa-envelope-o fa-fw"></i> Inbox</a>

          </li>
          <li><a href="#"><i class="fa fa-pencil-square-o fa-fw"></i> Drafts</a>

          </li>
          <li><a href="#"><i class="fa fa-paper-plane-o  fa-fw"></i> Sent Items</a>

          </li>
          <li class="divider"></li>
          <li><a href="#"><i class="fa fa-trash-o fa-fw"></i> Trash</a>

          </li>
        </ul>
      </li>
      <li><a href="#">Hello</a>

      </li>
      <li class="dropdown"> <a data-toggle="dropdown" class="dropdown-toggle" href="#">Things <b class="caret"></b></a>

        <ul role="menu" class="dropdown-menu">
          <li><a href="#"><i class="fa fa-envelope-o fa-fw"></i> Inbox</a>

          </li>
          <li><a href="#"><i class="fa fa-pencil-square-o  fa-fw"></i> Drafts</a>

          </li>
          <li><a href="#"><i class="fa fa-paper-plane-o  fa-fw"></i> Sent Items</a>

          </li>
          <li class="divider"></li>
          <li><a href="#"><i class="fa fa-trash-o fa-fw"></i> Trash</a>

            <li class="dropdown-submenu"> <a tabindex="-1" href="#"><i class="fa fa-hand-o-right fa-fw"></i> Profile</a>

              <ul class="dropdown-menu">
                <li><a tabindex="-1" href="#"><i class="fa fa-calendar-o fa-fw"></i> Account</a>

                </li>
                <li><a tabindex="-1" href="#"><i class="fa fa-folder-open-o  fa-fw"></i> Users</a>

                </li>
                <li><a tabindex="-1" href="#"><i class="fa fa-file-o fa-fw"></i> Login</a>

                </li>
              </ul>
            </li>
          </li>
        </ul>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</nav>
```